# numpyにおける"RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log"の対処方法

Tags: python, python3, numpy

Python 3.10.7 で下記のコードを動かしたところ警告が表示されます。

**実行時の警告:**

```
numpy_test.py:5: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  np_ret = np.where(np_val <= 0.5, np.sqrt(np_val), np.log(np_val))
[0.]
```

`print(ret_val)` の表示は `[0.]` ですので、`np_func()` は `np.sqrt(0)` の値を返していると考えています。
その為、おそらく `np_func()` に `np.zeros(1)` が渡された際に、条件を満たす `np.sqrt(np_val)` だけでなく、条件を満たさない `np.log(np_val)` も計算することで警告が出ているのだと思うのですが、認識はあっていますでしょうか？

できれば、今回のような実際には使用されない計算における警告は無視したいのですが、何か方法はありますでしょうか？

**ソースコード:**

```
import numpy as np


def np_func(np_val):
    np_ret = np.where(np_val <= 0.5, np.sqrt(np_val), np.log(np_val))
    return np_ret


def test_numpy():
    np_val = np.zeros(1)
    ret_val = np_func(np_val)
    print(ret_val)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_numpy()
```

Answer (score 2):

一時的に無視する方法

```py
def np_func(np_val):
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
        np_ret = np.where(np_val <= 0.5, np.sqrt(np_val), np.log(np_val))
    return np_ret
```

Answer (score 1):

warningsモジュールを利用するのは如何でしょうか．
(追記) コンテキストマネージャが利用できます．

```py
import warnings

import numpy as np


def np_func(np_val):
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
        np_ret = np.where(np_val <= 0.5, np.sqrt(np_val), np.log(np_val))
    return np_ret

def test_numpy():
    np_val = np.zeros(1)
    ret_val = np_func(np_val)
    print(ret_val)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_numpy()
```

参考: [warnings --- 警告の制御 / Python3.10.6 document](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter)

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。
上記のコードは、警告を一律で抑制するオプションという事ですよね。
できれば、np.whereのconditionと条件の異なる場合の警告だけを無視したいのですが、そのような記述は難しいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.log()` の `where` キーワードを使う方法もあります。

```py
def np_func(np_val):
    np_ret = np.where(np_val <= 0.5, np.sqrt(np_val), np.log(np_val, where=(np_val!=0)))
    return np_ret
```